# Enable/disable ProGuard in the product flavor

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

So, I know that in the build type the `runProguard 'bool'` directive can be used to tell whether ProGuard should be run or not. Unfortunately this directive does not work on the product flavors. Is there any way to specify if ProGuard should or not run in the flavors? I have thought of using a configuration file which basically says "do nothing", but (1) I don't know what should I write in it to forbid ProGuard from doing absolutely anything and (2) I don't think it's a good solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for this? The theory behind `runProguard` is that the decision is tied to build type (e.g., debug builds perhaps do not run ProGuard, release builds do).

Comment: @CommonsWare I use "two levels" of debug configuration. The first one is based on the build type: if the buildconfig is debug, the log calls in the app are printed. Then the second "level" allows me to debug and trace issues (ProGuard off), whereas if ProGuard is enabled this procedure is obviously impossible. The point is that I wwould like to have the possibility to have two apks with the "ProGuard off" configuration work with the release buildconfig - so that I have buildconfig release PG off, buildconfig release PG on (the one to publish), and buildconfig debug PG off.

Comment: But isn't that just a new build type? You can create your own build types, with different application ID suffixes, different ProGuard settings, etc.

Comment: Aha I didn't knew that, I thought the flavors were the only ones that could be created. That solves everything yes, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your scenario, it feels like you are trying to model different phases of your development lifecycle. That's really where build types are for. While Gradle (and hence Gradle for Android) ships with `debug` and `release` build types, you can define your own:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
      applicationIdSuffix ".d"
      versionNameSuffix "-debug"
    }

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    mezzanine.initWith(buildTypes.release)

    mezzanine {
        applicationIdSuffix ".mezz"
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

Here, I:

- Configure the `debug` and `release` build types
- Clone a `mezzanine` build type from `release`
- Override some settings on `mezzanine`, replacing what they had been defined as originally on `release`

Comment: Hi, Is there no way to specify different settings for different product flavors inside release variant?

Comment: @BharathMg: In general, product flavors are orthogonal to build types. IOW, any changes you want to a flavor for the release variant should also be changed for the debug variant. That being said, there may be some ways of dealing with specific settings in a way that might suit you. I suggest that you ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you explain your scenario and ask how to accomplish it.